# Android: Setting background of a ImageView to a ClipDrawable results in a Null object error?

Tags: java, android

I am creating an app in which a user clicks on a `Button` to input a selected image to an `ImageView`. Initially, the image is correctly cropped at 50% from the right, as shown in below:

[image]

Then, the user can drag the slider to the left to reveal less of the image, or right to reveal more of the image. However, **when the user moves the slider, the app crashes**, returning the following Null object error on the line of code where I set the `ImageView`'s background to the newly cropped image based on the slider's progress (`singlePreviewBox.setBackground(mClipDrawable);`).

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
> android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.getOpacity()' on a null object
> reference    at
> android.graphics.drawable.ClipDrawable.getOpacity(ClipDrawable.java:159)
> at android.view.View.computeOpaqueFlags(View.java:15698)    at
> android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:20502)    at
> android.view.View.setBackground(View.java:20395)    at
> com.example.changingimageviewwidth.MainActivity$1.onProgressChanged(MainActivity.java:49)

This seems strange, considering that the code performing the initial 50% crop from the right works, and I used that same code in my slider listener.

Below is my code:

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/transition_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/photo_input_1"
        android:onClick="chooseFile"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="No Photo"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="#f3f3f3"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:minHeight="40dp"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/image_reveal_slider"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="10"
        android:progress="5" />

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxHeight="370dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.changingimageviewwidth;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.ClipDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.InputStream;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    // Request code used when reading in a file
    private Integer READ_IN_FILE = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SeekBar imageRevealSlider = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.image_reveal_slider);
        // perform seek bar change listener event used for getting the progress value
        imageRevealSlider.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            int progressChangedValue = 0;

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                progressChangedValue = progress;

                ImageView singlePreviewBox = findViewById(R.id.image_container);
                singlePreviewBox.invalidate();

                ClipDrawable mClipDrawable = new ClipDrawable(singlePreviewBox.getDrawable(), 11,
                        ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
                mClipDrawable.setLevel((progress / 10) * 10000);
                singlePreviewBox.setImageResource(0);
                singlePreviewBox.setBackground(mClipDrawable);
            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Seek bar progress is :" + progressChangedValue,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void chooseFile(View v) {
        // Specify that only photos are allowed as inputs (.jpg, .png).
        Intent photoInputSpecs = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        photoInputSpecs.setType("image/*");

        Intent photoInputHandler = Intent.createChooser(photoInputSpecs, "Choose a file");
        startActivityForResult(photoInputHandler, READ_IN_FILE);
    }

    // Processes the results of Activities.
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        try {
            // Processes the photos that the user selected
            if (requestCode == READ_IN_FILE) {
                // Retrieve the photo's location
                Uri photoUri = data.getData();

                InputStream photoInputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
                System.out.println("[photoInputStream.available()] = " + photoInputStream.available());
                Bitmap photoBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),
                        photoUri);
                // Display the selected image in the preview box
                displayPhoto(photoUri);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("onActivityResult error: " + ex.toString());
        }
    }

    // Displays a specified photo in the split and single screen preview boxes.
    private void displayPhoto(Uri photoUri) {
        ImageView singlePreviewBox = findViewById(R.id.image_container);
        singlePreviewBox.invalidate();
        singlePreviewBox.setImageURI(photoUri);

        ClipDrawable mClipDrawable = new ClipDrawable(singlePreviewBox.getDrawable(), 11,
                                                      ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
        mClipDrawable.setLevel(5000);
        singlePreviewBox.setImageResource(0);
        singlePreviewBox.setBackground(mClipDrawable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed several problems with your code.

**Null Pointer Exception**

- If your `ImageView` has no image, your app will crash. This is something that you need to check beforehand.

**Math**

- `mClipDrawable.setLevel((progress / 10) * 10000);` Division between integers might causes a faction loss. So you either have to cast one of them or both; like this one.

```java
mClipDrawable.setLevel((int)((progress / 10F) * 10000F));
```

**The Use of Methods**

- `singlePreviewBox.setImageResource(0);` You're setting an image to your `ImageView`, soon after you're setting it with a different method. You don't even need this method by the way. Even the use of this method is incorrect. It supposed to look like this:

```java
singlePreviewBox.setImageResource(R.drawable.myImage);
```

Comment: In the line of code "singlePreviewBox.setImageResource(R.drawable.myImage);", I can't hardcode a drawable value (R.drawable.myImage), since the drawable can be any image the user has selected. Also, when I try detecting if the ImageView has an image through "singlePreviewBox.getDrawable() != null", it always returns null.

Comment: 1) As I said, you don't need that line. 2) Just use a boolean variable. Put one in `displayPhoto()`, check that variable in `onProgressChanged()` and don't forget to set/reset it to `false` first probably in `onActivityResult()` or `onCreate()`.